# Extract nth element from underscore separated string

Tags: r, extract, gsub

I want to extract `myproducta` and `myproductb`.

I think by regex is ok, but only works for: cc string, but not for `aa`. Howcome? Both have same length.

```
aa <- "e220juju_uk_yy_aon_aon_conversion_mystore_facebook-network_ppl_primaria_myproducta_galaxycombos_20220520"
cc <- "e220tyty_bo_oo_aon_aon_conversion_mystore_facebook-network_ppl_lal_myproductb_wd95m4473mw_diasdecyber_20220718"
```

regex part:

```
gsub(cc, pattern = ".*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_(.*)_.*_.*_.*", replacement = "\\1", perl = TRUE) #works: returns: myproductb

gsub(aa, pattern = ".*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_.*_(.*)_.*_.*_.*", replacement = "\\1", perl = TRUE) #don't work: returns: primaria
```

Comment: Instead of `.*` use `[^_]+`

Comment: @akrun Or use lazy dot `.*?`

Comment: @rawr yes, but the difference happens after the part i'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use anchors and a negated character class, and then repeat 10 times matching an underscore before capturing the 11th occurrence.

```
^(?:[^_]*_){10}([^_]*).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/82XFyW/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##lc3BSsQwEIDhe58iBA/t0pW27rIqiidfQPRk3WGSxqXbNBOS1BrEZ69lXVwELx4GZuAfPjdNiOxmybiqqmI/7AcYOogRkMxhJJk35Xw7r330gZyCV5RKEHVLo8JIrgNrNVjX9uhanCvrqBlkQNihxvcoqRfkoSpmYF0VPJHyBwwxRBAERP8GNeqTJWBsrtb9arW56EdoWvSNklEo981uykueJBZDUM4c8G16d/28hdq8LCD7KIvP9Hhl54uzud35QaTHh5zxui55zhBzZpXT7JY9PjzdZ39XUv6upukL)

```
aa <- "e220juju_uk_yy_aon_aon_conversion_mystore_facebook-network_ppl_primaria_myproducta_galaxycombos_20220520"
cc <- "e220tyty_bo_oo_aon_aon_conversion_mystore_facebook-network_ppl_lal_myproductb_wd95m4473mw_diasdecyber_20220718"

pattern <- "^(?:[^_]*_){10}([^_]*).*$"

gsub(pattern, "\\1", aa, perl = TRUE)
gsub(pattern, "\\1", cc, perl = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[1] "myproducta"
[1] "myproductb"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approaches

```
read.table(text = aa, sep = "_")[[11]]
## [1] "myproducta"

strsplit(aa, "_")[[1]][11]
## [1] "myproducta"

scan(text = aa, sep = "_", what = "", quiet = TRUE)[11]
## [1] "myproducta"

sub("^(([^_]*)_){10}([^_]*)_.*", "\\3", aa)
## [1] "myproducta"
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work with a data frame... I'll try to post a dummy example.

Comment: `strsplit(test$campaign, "_")[[1]][11]` only returns the result for the first element.

Comment: This answers the question as asked, not some other question which was not asked. At any rate try this where DF is a test data frame: `DF <- data.frame(x = c(aa, cc)); transform(DF, prod = sapply(strsplit(x, "_"), "[", 11))`